# How can I create a Google Sheets script to generate hyperlinks to corresponding tabs based on cell value?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, links

I have a list and want to quickly add a hyperlink to the corresponding tab.
Say my list is in column BC and looks like:

```
A
B
C
A
C
B
```

I would like all the A's to have a hyperlink to the sheet within the same google sheet to go to the sheet labeled "A".

It is quite a long list and would like to save time rather than hyperlinking each cell at a time by running a script of some sort.

I tried this:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  var sheet = e.source.getActiveSheet();

  var range = sheet.getActiveRange();

  var val   = range.getValues();

  var col   = range.getColumn();

  var row   = range.getRow();

  var h_string = '=HYPERLINK("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QUICa667obThNZY3yXf-9MCc1Q3_-YEtvhVFn6tb6cI/edit#gid=1910200599'+val+'","'+val+'")';

  if(col == 55) { 

    cell = sheet.getRange(col+row);

    cell.setFormula(h_string);

  }

}
```

but line 2 doesn't work and I don't know why.

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Maybe you should start by reading https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Programmatically create an internal hyperlink](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/112196/programmatically-create-an-internal-hyperlink)